# How to prevent the login block to be shown twice?

Tags: blocks, users

When I open my web without being logged in, the login block appears twice. Once in sidebar and once in header (at least I hope it is header section), as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

However, in structure/blocks I have it set in sidebar only.

Any idea how to fix this, so that the login block is only shown once?
Theme is ANDROMEDA: https://www.drupal.org/project/andromeda

Comment: you need to check on page.tpl.php file present inside theme folder

Comment: Ive looked there, but not sure what to look for :-(

Comment: Using mozilla firebug I found the element and managed to delete it in firebug console. BUt still don¨t know where it is in the template files :-(.

Comment: Check weather login form is rendered in the header section in tpl file.Both page.tpl.php and page--front.tpl(if present)

Comment: Well, I kind of solved it...I deleted the whole Andromeda folder and copied it again. The unwanted block disappeared...but I know its not the best solution. I should have set up Andromeda sub-theme. But forgot. Thanx all for advice

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps, Using which can solve your problem.

1. Go to Blocks under structure admin menu.
2. You will find user login block in Header section.
3. If you have added your custom login block then there is no need to have default login widget in header. So change it to null.
4. If you have default login then just check to put it in appropriate block.

This are the two cases according to your question description.Answer back if not solved.

Please do mention some more description if this solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of some theme setting that is turned on, so check if that's the case and if so, turn that theme setting of.

Alternatively, do not display the block in the sidebar (at least until you find the solution for removing it from the header, if that's what you prefer).

Also, consider editing your question to also explain which theme you are using (with link to it on drupal.org). Or mentioned that you're using a custom theme, if that is the case.

Comment: Great, thanx, i ll check it out. And yes, im idiot, I ll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you found the element in firebug, you can also try hiding it with css.

Comment: Not a good way to do things... :(